# Confirm "pop-up" message in casperjs

Tags: casperjs

I'm trying to automate a Cloudflare cache purge of my websites with casperjs.

The button to purge cache has this source code:

```
<a class="button green mini" id="Purge" name="PurgeButton"><span class="label">Purge cache</span></a>
```

but when I click on it, a "pop-up" message asks me to confirm:

[image]

I have no clue how to click on "Yes, purge everything". I don't see this text anywhere in the source code and actually I don't even know what happens when I first click on "Purge cache" !

How can I validate this popup?

**Edit: Solved: the "view source" option in Firefox doesn't allow to see the full source code, instead install the developer toolbar add-on and go to "View source > View generated source"**

Comment: This question is really unanswerable. Only someone you has a Cloudflare account could look into it, but this is not the purpose of SO. Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Except if this is a general problem arising when one adds content to his div through javascript or jquery. I'm not knowledgeable enough to be sure but it would seem surprising Cloudflare is the only one using this technique, and I suspect there exists a general solution independent of the Cloudflare implementation. But I can provide the full source code from Cloudflare if you want.

Comment: If content is added, it will be visible when you look into it with the developer tools of your browser. Of course, don't use "view source", because it is static snapshot of the page that was received over the wire.

Comment: @ArtjomB. that was the problem, I was looking at the static source...